# Roblox, change team

Tags: roblox

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
    player.TeamColor = BrickColor.new("Really red")
    player:LoadCharacter()
end)
```

Error:
Players.unknown.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.Frame.Red.Script:3: attempt to index nil with 'TeamColor'  -  Server - Script:3

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Local Script and not just Script

Answer (score 0):

`LocalPlayer` can't be called in a server script. You either have to use a `LocalScript` or change the code to work in a server script.